# How do I get data into the ndarray format for SKLearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

Scikit-Learn is a great Python module that supplies a [support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) with many algorithms. I've been learning how to use the module for the past few days, and I've noticed it relies heavily on the separate [numpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) module.

I understand what the module does, but I'm still learning about how it works. Here is a very brief example of what I'm using `sklearn` for:

```
from sklearn import datasets, svm
import numpy

digits = datasets.load_digits() #image pixel data of digits 0-9 as well as a chart of the corresponding digit to each image

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001,C=100) #SVC is the algorithm used for classifying this type of data

x,y = digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1] #feed it all the data
clf.fit(x,y) #"train" the SVM

print(clf.predict(digits.data[0])) #>>>[0]
#with 99% accuracy, all of the data consists of 1797 samples.
#if this number gets smaller, the accuracy decreases. with 10 samples (0-9),
#accuracy can still be up to as high as 90%.
```

That's very basic classification. **There are 10 classes: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.**

Using the following code with matplotlib.pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #in shell after running previous code
plt.imshow(digits.images[0],cmap=plt.cm.gray_r,interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

gives the following image:
[image]

The first pixel (left to right, top to bottom, like reading) would be represented by a 0. Same for the second, but the third would be represented by 7 or something (range is 0 to 15), fourth being about 13. Here's the actual data for the image:

```
[[  0.   0.   5.  13.   9.   1.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  13.  15.  10.  15.   5.   0.]
 [  0.   3.  15.   2.   0.  11.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  12.   0.   0.   8.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   5.   8.   0.   0.   9.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  11.   0.   1.  12.   7.   0.]
 [  0.   2.  14.   5.  10.  12.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   6.  13.  10.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

**So my question is this:** if I wanted to classify text data, for example forum posts in the wrong subforum/category, how would I convert that data into the number system used in this dataset example?

Comment: You would need to flatten it out to a single vector. So your numpy array would be nx64, where n is the number of images and each column represents one pixel in your image. Obviously you lose a lot of interesting information with this representation of your image, which is one the reasons why convolutional neural networks are, generally speaking, far superior when it comes to image classification.

Answer (score 0):

For each sample(e.g each Forum Post) you must have a vector(in python a list). For example if you have 200 post and their respective category, you must have 200 list for training data and exactly one list that has 200 element for each 200 category.
each list of traning category can be a model(e.g Bag Of Word. see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model). Notice that all list for training must have same element(same dimention)(for example each list must have 3000 element that each element reperesnt present or absent of a word)
Try to look at this, it's easy for begginers: https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words